# Simple jquery slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I'm using mousewheel jQuery plugin and trying to create a simple slider. Here is a example but slider next and prev button not working properly.

```js
$('.container').mousewheel(function(event, delta) {
      this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 40);
      event.preventDefault();
});


// next & prev option

//prev

$('.prev').click(function(){
         $('.storepos').val($('.storepos').val() / 1 - 110);
         $('.container').animate({scrollLeft:$('.storepos').val()}, 200);
     });


//next

  $('.next').click(function(){
         $('.storepos').val($('.storepos').val() / 1 + 110);
         $('.container').animate({scrollLeft:$('.storepos').val()}, 200);
     });
```

```css
.container{overflow-x:scroll}
.content {width:1600px}
.items { background:black;
       color:white;
       margin-left:10px;
       width:100px;
       height:100px;
       float:left;
       text-align:center
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mousewheel/3.1.13/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<div class="content">
<div class="items">1</div>
<div class="items">2</div>
<div class="items">3</div>
<div class="items">4</div>
<div class="items">5</div>
<div class="items">6</div>
<div class="items">7</div>
<div class="items">8</div>
<div class="items">9</div>
<div class="items">10</div>
</div>
</div>
<a href="#" class="prev">Prev</a> / <a href="#" class="next">Next</a>
<input class="storepos" value="" />
```

Need to stop position update when next / prev items ended.

Comment: check in your onclick function the value through if statement of your storepos element. It should do the work

Comment: Yes but how to fix it? i'm new in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

check in your onclick function the value through if statement of your storepos element

**Previous button**

```
$('.prev').click(function(){
    var storepos = $(".storepos").val();
    if(storepos == 0){
        //Do nothing
    }else{
        $('.storepos').val($('.storepos').val() / 1 - 110);
        $('.container').animate({scrollLeft:$('.storepos').val()}, 200);
    }
});
```

**Next button**

**Updated**

```
$('.next').click(function(){
    var storepos = $(".storepos").val();
    var maxLength = (($(".items").length * 110) / 2);
    if(storepos == maxLength){
        //Do nothing
    }else{
        $('.storepos').val($('.storepos').val() / 1 + 110);
        $('.container').animate({scrollLeft:$('.storepos').val()}, 200);
    }
});
```

Comment: Same, just use the 550 value, as you can see that the 10th element has a value of 550

Comment: No i don't want that. Is there any other option??

Comment: What do you mean by "I don't want that" ... ?

Comment: I created a dynamically add or remove items option so next button need to auto detect that. I think you understand.

Comment: So it's easy calculation then... count the number of elements and then multiply by 110 = your value of the maximum length

Comment: @Geomo - I updated my answer to fix your problem. Hope this helps

Comment: I mean there is no error from my side of code. You must check yourself some stuff to go ahead. We dont see your dynamic add or remove code

Comment: I tested with my above given example but not worked.

Comment: Next button not stop update but prev button working.

Comment: What value did you get from maxLength?

Comment: Try it now. I updated the question and i found mistake

Comment: It works. You didnt see my updated answer. See it again... it works

Comment: i copy and paste your code but not worked you can see your example here https://jsfiddle.net/ktd205x8/1/

Comment: Yes it is pretty obvious that it will take effect on window resize. That's why you should use percentages. But okay. If you don't even understand the very basics of coding then Im done here